# Setting 3 routers with GNS3

Tags: networking

I have three routers in GNS3, each router connected to first router forming like this, /\

I am using class B address 142.55.0.0 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 to configure the network.
Moreover, I tried creating four subnets as required. How do I do static routing between these three routers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this then:

```
RA = Router A
RB = Router B
RC = Router 3

In = inside interface
Out = outside interface

-- Router
---- Patch cable
```

So:

```
RA In -- RA Out ---- RB In -- RB Out ---- RC Out -- RC in
```

RB is in the middle so "inside" and "outside" don't mean anything, just labels.

So you want to route from RA In to RC In.

On RA, you need

```
route <RC inside subnet> <RC inside subnet mask> <RB in>
```

On RC you need

```
route <RA inside subnet> <RA inside subnet mask> <RB Out>
```

On RB you need

```
route <RA inside subnet> <RA inside subnet mask> <RA Out>
route <RC inside subnet> <RC inside subnet mask> <RC Out>
```

Comment: what is RA out?

Comment: The key is at the top of the post.  RA = Router A, Out = outside interface.  So RA Out = Router A outside interface.